# Why a Text widget is not taking the style defined in the theme?

Tags: flutter, themes

When I wrote the following code, I expected the text to be red:

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    buttonTheme: Theme.of(context)
        .buttonTheme
        .copyWith(buttonColor: Colors.yellow),
  ),
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text('Flutter'),
          Text('is awesome!'),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('OK'),
          )
        ],
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

but the text was black while the button was yellow as you can see:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AoM0.png)

As you can see the `Text` widgets ignored the style defined in the theme while the `RaisedButton` didn't. Why?

I know that I can use `DefaultTextStyle` instead but I'm trying to understand why is that not working like I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` widget has `style` property. As we can see from [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/Text.html):

```
If the [style] argument is null, the text will use the style from the
closest enclosing [DefaultTextStyle].
```

It is clear, Text uses style from `DefaultTextStyle` widget (not from `Theme`) if you didn't specify it as you did. If you want to use style from theme you should specify it explicitly:

```
 Text('Flutter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)
```

As for buttons - any MaterialButton child (RaisedButton too) use `ButtonTheme.of(context).textTheme` as default value of `textTheme` property.

Comment: Thank you! It does make sense but still looks weird for me as we don't need to explicitly add a `DefaultTextStyle` if we define a theme at `MaterialApp` level.